# MQTT Android Client Call CalBackListener Problems

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I code a service to subscribe message from mqtt server. Service auto reconnect when internet connection on/off.

This code:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service{

    private Handler connectBrokerHandler;
    private ConnectBrokerTimerTask connectBrokerTimerTask;
    private Timer connectBrokerTimer;

    private MqttAndroidClient androidClient;
    private MqttConnectOptions connectOptions;
    private MemoryPersistence memPer;
    private IMqttToken connectToken;
    private CustomActionListener customActionListener;
    private Context context;
    private String CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_INIT;

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationService";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "chuxuanhy";
    private static final String PASS_WORD = "0936160721";
    private static final String URL_BROKER = "tcp://ntm.diyoracle.com:1883";
    private static final String TOPIC_STAFF = "PROSHIP_STAFF";
    private static final String DEVICE_ID = "FUCKYOU_002";
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 60;
    private static final int KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL = 60*60;
    private static final int TRY_CONNECTION_DELAY = 30; //seconds

    private static final String CLIENT_INIT = "CLIENT_INIT";
    private static final String CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_START = "CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_START";
    private static final String CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_FAIL = "CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_FAIL";
    private static final String CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_SUCCESS = "CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_SUCCESS";
    private static final String CLIENT_LOST_CONNECTION = "CLIENT_LOST_CONNECTION";
    private static final String CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_START = "CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_START";
    private static final String CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_FAIL = "CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_FAIL";
    private static final String CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_SUCCESS = "CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_SUCCESS";

    private IntentFilter FilterNetwork;
    private BroadcastReceiver ReceiverCheckInternet = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(isOnline()){
                if(CLIENT_STATUS == CLIENT_LOST_CONNECTION || CLIENT_STATUS == CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_FAIL || CLIENT_STATUS == CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_FAIL) {
                    ConnectBroker();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private class ConnectBrokerTimerTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connectBrokerHandler.post(ConnectBrokerRunable);
        }
    }

    private Runnable ConnectBrokerRunable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConnectBroker();
        }
    };

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    public void RestartNotificationService(){
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePendingIntent);
    }

    public void createNotification(String title, String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.train).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000})
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentText(body).build();

        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(m, notification);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        try{
            RestartNotificationService();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(ReceiverCheckInternet);
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        try{
            if(androidClient.isConnected()){
                this.androidClient.unsubscribe(TOPIC_STAFF);
                this.androidClient.disconnect();
                this.androidClient = null;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void ConnectBroker(){
        try {
            CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_START;
            connectToken = this.androidClient.connect(connectOptions,null,customActionListener);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectBroker Fail Exception");
        }
    }

    private void SubscribeBrokerTopic(String topic){
        try {
            CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_START;
            androidClient.subscribe(topic, 0, null, customActionListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "SubscribeBrokerTopic Fail Exception");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("NOTIFI","CALL ME onStartCommand");
        this.connectBrokerHandler = new Handler();
        this.connectBrokerTimer = new Timer();
        this.connectBrokerTimerTask = new ConnectBrokerTimerTask();

        this.customActionListener = new CustomActionListener();

        this.memPer = new MemoryPersistence();
        this.connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        this.connectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
        this.connectOptions.setUserName(USER_NAME);
        this.connectOptions.setPassword(PASS_WORD.toCharArray());
        this.connectOptions.setConnectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        this.connectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL);

        this.androidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(),URL_BROKER,DEVICE_ID,memPer);
        this.androidClient.setCallback(new CustomCallBack());
        this.androidClient.setTraceCallback(new CustomTraceHandler());

        //this.androidClient.

        this.FilterNetwork = new IntentFilter();
        this.FilterNetwork.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        registerReceiver(ReceiverCheckInternet, FilterNetwork);

        //this.androidClient.registerResources(getApplicationContext());
        ConnectBroker();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private class CustomTraceHandler implements MqttTraceHandler{
        @Override
        public void traceDebug(String source, String message) {
            Log.e(TAG,"CustomConnectHandler - traceDebug\n"+source+" - "+message);
        }

        @Override
        public void traceError(String source, String message) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CustomConnectHandler - traceError\n" + source + " - " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void traceException(String source, String message, Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CustomConnectHandler - traceException\n" + source + " - " + message);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class CustomCallBack implements MqttCallback{
        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
            CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_LOST_CONNECTION;

            if(!isOnline()){
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectCallBack connectionLost - No Internet Connection ");
            }else {
                //throwable.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            Log.e(TAG,"ConnectCallBack messageArrived\n"+s+" - "+mqttMessage.toString());
            createNotification(s, mqttMessage.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectCallBack deliveryComplete");
        }
    }

    private class CustomActionListener implements IMqttActionListener {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
            if (CLIENT_STATUS == CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_START) {
                CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_SUCCESS;
                if (iMqttToken.getTopics() == null) {
                    SubscribeBrokerTopic(TOPIC_STAFF);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "CustomActionListener - CONNECT BROKER onSuccess");
            } else if (CLIENT_STATUS == CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_START) {
                CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_SUCCESS;
                Log.e(TAG, "CustomActionListener - SUBSCRIBE TOPIC onSuccess");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
            if (CLIENT_STATUS == CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_START) {
                CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_CONNECTION_BROKER_FAIL;
                Log.e(TAG, "CustomActionListener - CONNECT BROKER onFailure ");
            } else if (CLIENT_STATUS == CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_START) {
                CLIENT_STATUS = CLIENT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_FAIL;
                Log.e(TAG, "CustomActionListener - SUBSCRIBE TOPIC onFailure ");
            }
            if (isOnline()) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                //connectBrokerTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(connectBrokerTimerTask, 5000, TRY_CONNECTION_DELAY * 1000);
            }else {
                Log.e(TAG, "CustomActionListener onFailure - No Internet Connection ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But i have a problem, every time internet connection lost, i reconnect server, callback call again.
Example:

```
Log.e(TAG, "ConnectCallBack connectionLost - No Internet Connection ");
```

call twice, 3 time, 4 time every disconnect internet
Sorry my english not good, thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't handle the re-connection manually, newer version of paho has option to auto reconnect in MqttConnectOptions class.

```
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.1'
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
```